# Bitcoin core causing reboot

Tags: bitcoin-core, client

I have been having an issue with bitcoin core lately. It has been causing my computer to randomly reboot about every hour or so. I was on version 17.1 but upgraded to 18.0 hoping that would fix the issue but no dice. I am running it on Linux Mint 19.1 on an Intel Nuc. I regularly update by system and have all current updates. I see nothing wrong in the bitcoin debug log or in the Linux system log. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
C

Comment: Can you add more info for the configuration bitcoin core? you can see the resources of the system during the System is ran?

Comment: How have you determined that Bitcoin Core is causing it and not a more general cause like a hardware issue?

Comment: Nothing in Bitcoin Core can cause a reboot. You have some severe hardware failure.

Comment: Vince - do you mean my bitcoin.conf file?

Comment: I’m pretty sure Bitcoin Core is doing something that causes the reboot. I’m not saying it specifically calls for the computer to reboot but it is the cause. I’m pretty sure because the computer is fine when bitcoin core is not running. It only happens when either Bitcoin-Qt or bitcoind is running